# Rials Routing Error:Because of Controller name different from model name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, visual-studio-code, ruby-on-rails-6

everyone! I am new to rails and working on Codecademy tutorials. But I wanted to see if I can run the same app on my mac using VS Code and got into some roadblocks. The application is basically to create a form that takes in messages and displays it (in the index view). I wanted to explore changing the names of controller and model to what I want and guess I messed up the internal routing. Following is the controller (messagec)

```
class MessagecController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @messages1 = MessagesMo1.all
    end

    def new
        @messages2 = MessagesMo1.new
    end

    def create
        @messages2 = MessagesMo1.new(message_params)
        if @messages2.save #tells if the object is saved successfully in db or not
           flash[:success] = "Great! Your post has been created!"
           redirect_to '/messages'
        else
          flash.now[:error] = "Fix your mistakes, please."
          render 'new'
        end
    end

    private
    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:content)
    end
end
```

THe following is the model (messagesmo1)

```
class CreateMessagesMo1s < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :messages_mo1s do |t|
      t.text :content
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The following is the routes.rb file

```
get '/messages' => 'messagec#index'
get '/messages/new' => 'messagec#new'
post 'messages' => 'messagec#create'
post 'messages_mo1s' => 'message_mo1s#create'
```

The following is the code in create.html.erb file

```
    <%= form_for(@messages2) do |f| %>
    <div class = "field">
        <%= f.label :message %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :content %>
    </div>
    <div class = "actions">
    <%= f.submit "Create" %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

I am able to see the message list and able to go to create new message page. But when I submit the form, I am getting the following Routing error:

**uninitialized constant MessageMo1sController Did you mean? MessagecController MessagesMController**

My first questions is:
1) What am I missing in the routes.rb file?
2) Is there any rule between naming the model similar to that of the controller?

Comment: I think you have to change the `form_for` arguments (and/or use `form_with`). The routes are fine, although it is advised to follow the "standard" path and name simple CRUD controllers according to the models. That is - if your application workflow (UI) really goes along creating, updating, etc. these models.

Comment: Rails doesn't care what your controller is called — at least, in relation to the models it communicates with. You could have `AsdfsController` and `Mustang` class if you wanted.

Comment: The form_for might be okay because I am able to see the form. But I think the problem is when I submit the form, i.e in the 'create' action. Once I click on submit, it is redirecting to 'local server/messages_mo1s' address. And I did not give that part anywhere. It should either direct me to '/messages' page or 'messages/new' page right? (since thats what is in under 'create' action in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replicated all of the above, I think there are many things to keep in mind.

1. Your model file must be of name `messagesmo1.rb` and in this model:

   ```rb
   class MessagesMo1 < ApplicationRecord
   end
   ```
2. Your controller file should be of name `messagec_controller.rb` and in it:

   ```rb
   def index
     @messages1 = MessagesMo1.all
   end

   def new
     @messages2 = MessagesMo1.new
   end

   def create
     @messages2 = MessagesMo1.new(message_params)
     if @messages2.save #tells if the object is saved successfully in db or not
       flash[:success] = "Great! Your post has been created!"
       redirect_to '/messages'
     else

       flash.now[:error] = "Fix your mistakes, please."
       redirect_to '/messages/new'
     end
   end

   private
   def message_params
     params.require(:messages_mo1).permit(:content)
   end
   ```
3. In the above point, look at the `message_params` part, it must be `:messages_mo1` and not `:message`
4. No changes required in `_form.html.erb` file
5. Your migration file must be of name `timestamp__create_messages_mo1s.rb` and it must have:

   ```rb
   class CreateMessagesMo1s < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
     def change
       create_table :messages_mo1s do |t|
         t.text :content

         t.timestamps
       end
     end
   end
   ```
6. In your `routes.rb` file, change the last route:

   ```rb
   get '/messages' => 'messagec#index'
   get '/messages/new' => 'messagec#new'
   post 'messages' => 'messagec#create'
   post 'messages_mo1s' => 'messagec#create'
   ```
7. Make sure all your links are updated in `index.html.erb`, in `show.html.erb` and in `new.html.erb` -> Like links to show, delete, edit etc. Or if your just testing remove these links.
8. After making above changes, run `rails db:drop db:create db:migrate` as it will clean your DB of old migration.
9. That's it, now everything should work. The main problem is naming convention should be standard across all files. So it's better to use standard convention.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One question: the model file name has underscore in it. Tails created it automatically. So instead of messagesmo1.rb, it is messages_mo1.rb. Do I have to manually change it?

Comment: Do I need to chaange something in the new.html.erb file like near 'form_for' OR near 'f.submit'?

Comment: in addition to the params update you mentioned, I had to change the URL too. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked. Following are the 2 changes: 
1) Instead of `<%= form_for(@messages2) do |f| %>`, I used a URL parameter
  `<%= form_for(@messages2, url:'/messages/') do |f| %>`
2)As @cdadityang mentioned, I updated the params to `params.require(:messages_mo1).permit(:content)`

without the URL being given explicitly, I think the rails is assuming '/message_mo1' are the path. So the URL is basically taking it to 'messagec#create'